# Editor that supports renaming tabs for untitled docs?

Tags: windows, text-editors

I sometimes need to copy/paste text into two windows and compare the contents for a quick hack, ie. without having to save both documents to disk, and display the two docs side-by-side vertically so I can scroll them independantly ([WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/about/screenshots/) doesn't seem to support independent scrolling.)

Since the documents only live in RAM, text editors will display a non-descript tab/filename like "Untitled1" or "New file 1":

[image]

Does someone know of a Windows editor that supports...

- renaming tabs with more descriptive names even with documents that haven't been saved to disk,
- side-by-side, vertical tiling, and
- independant scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

[Vim](http://vim.sourceforge.net/) will do that. The [Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/) version has an interface that is more consistent with other Windows programs.

First start gvim. Create two side-by-side windows by executing `:vnew`. Paste your documents into the two windows. To show their differences, execute `:windo diffthis`. The two windows scroll together by default. To make them scroll independently, execute `:set noscrollbind`. To name each window, click in the window to select it, then execute `:f somename` where *somename* is the name you've chosen for that document.